# Load jQuery in iframe and use ajax of it

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, iframe

I have created hta application with iframes for crossdomain requests, because i cannot launch my own server to proxify those.

At main page i have inserted jQuery script and iframe of "victim" site, for example: google.com

```
<iframe name="iframe" src="http://google.com" application="yes"></iframe>
```

Now i must do AJAX POST request thru that iframe, here is the code:

```
var frame = document.frames.iframe;
frame.$ = $
frame.$.ajax({
    type : 'post'
    url : 'http://google.com'
    data : 'blablabla'
});
```

But iframe gives me "No Transport" error. But when i am doing script element on victim page, all is ok, for example:

```
var frame = document.frames.iframe.document;
var el = frame.createEelement('SCRIPT');
el.src = "file://urlToJs.js";
frame.appendChild(el);
```

And with this example all works fine, but i haven't internet at work (we work with local sites)... And create another js file to load I also do not want.

Help me pleasee!

What i have tried:

- take script element text (document.scripts[0].innerHTML) and create
  script with text in iframe [Error]
- document.frames.iframes.$ = parent.$ [Also don't work, No Transport error]

It seems that jQuery ajax always uses main page to create request, how i can fix that?

Comment: If the iframe is of a differen't domain, you can't do anything to it.

Comment: In hta with attribute: application="yes" can access also crossdomain. Found an answer, answer is $.support.cors = true and in ajax crossDomain : true.

Answer (score 0):

jquery collect everything it need on script loading.

you can see something like this in jquery source file:

```
(function factory( window ){ // a huge closure around the entire file
    var doc = window.document;

    window.$ = function(){
        // do something with the "doc"
    }
})( window );  // <- init with current window
```

so wherever you assign variable $, the "document" will not change.

jquery do this for performance issue ( maybe something other?

you need edit jquery source, extract the "factory" function ...

> ( function factory(){} )() ==extract==> function factory(){}

and call it with iframe's window

> factory(iframe.contentWindow);

then you can use iframe.contentWindow.$ as you want.